# PHP file with accompanying compiled file

Tags: php, html, smarty3

I have inherited a php system written using Smarty. The code is split into class files and templates which I can work my way through. However, for each template file, there is another file written similarly to the template file but with a strange name. For example, I have a footer.tpl file with this code:

```html
<div id="footer">
 <p class="bold">Class Management, Version 3.6.4 (<a href="change_log.txt">Version History/Change Log</a>)</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p><img src="images/design/logo_small.gif" /></p>
 <p>Work Limited</p>
 <p>Registered Office: Work address</p>
 <p>Tel: Work tel</p>
</div>
```

The accompanying file has the name %%0E^0E4^0E407559%%footer.tpl.php with the following code

```html
<?php /* Smarty version 2.6.19, created on 2013-07-31 13:27:22
         compiled from footer.tpl */ ?>
<div id="footer">
 <p class="bold">Class Management, Version 3.6.4 (<a href="change_log.txt">Version History/Change Log</a>)</p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <p><img src="images/design/logo_small.gif" /></p>
 <p>Work Limited</p>
 <p>Registered Office: Work address</p>
 <p>Tel: Work tel</p>
</div>
```

So, my question is, if I create a new template file, how could I create or what would I use to create the accompanying .tpl.php file?

Any pointers at all to give me a direction to start looking in gratefully received.

Many thanks.

Comment: The template will be compiled/created when the new template is first accessed.

Answer (score 2):

That's a cached copy of the file, the variables are filled in (compiled) so next time its called it does not have to be recreated saving load time, processor time, bandwidth. You dont have to create that file your self they are handled internally. (assuming things are set up properly)

footer.tpl has no variables, some what unusual, so its not really an issue, but most template files should (have variables)